# Landscape home server

Tags: server, landscape

I have installed Landscape to manage my home computers. I have almost all the computers registered in Landscape, but I am wondering if I should also configure my own Landscape server to be managed by Landscape itself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, having Landscape manage itself works just fine!